# Timeout configuration in WCF

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

It is really weird that for this configuration, the service actually timed out in just one minute. Isn't "01:00:00" one hour? Or for different timeout property, it uses different format? Is there a documentation for this? Thanks!

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBindingBigMessages" 
         closeTimeout="00:59:00" 
         openTimeout="00:59:00" 
         receiveTimeout="00:59:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:59:00" 
         allowCookies="false" 
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
         maxBufferSize="1000000000" 
         maxBufferPoolSize="100000000" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" 
         messageEncoding="Text" 
         textEncoding="utf-8" 
         transferMode="Buffered" 
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">

  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                maxStringContentLength="819200" 
                maxArrayLength="1638400" 
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
```

This is the error message I saw in my code in debug mode:

> {"The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 01:00:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."}

Comment: Try adding <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/> to your service behaviour element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over the client and server configuration? It could be a timeout on the server (via [HttpRuntime setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx)).

```
<system.web>
    <!-- Maximum 10 min timeout -->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks and now I got "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.", any idea of possible reason?

Comment: How large is your message/payload?

Answer (score 1):

"01:00:00" is indeed 1 hour.

The default operation timeout on a WCF client is 1 minute. Are you properly setting the timeout on the clients? It could be timing out here.